# Type error using _.flatten with items of different types

Tags: typescript, types, lodash, flatten

In my TypeScript code, I've got an error for Lodash's `_.flatten` function. The code still works, but TS is giving an error. The error can be found below, in the comments in the code.

How can I resolve this issue?

```js
import _ from 'lodash';

interface Item {
  text: string;
}

const item: Item = {
  text: 'string',
};

const arr = ['a'];

/**

Argument of type '(Item | string[])[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayLike<Many<string>>'.
  Index signatures are incompatible.
    Type 'Item | string[]' is not assignable to type 'Many<string>'.
      Type 'Item' is not assignable to type 'Many<string>'.
        Type 'Item' is missing the following properties from type 'readonly string[]': length, concat, join, slice, and 18 more.

 */
const flattened = _.flatten([arr, item]);

console.log(flattened);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the generic type parameter on `flatten` to let TS know that values can be either  `string` or `Item`:

```
const flattened = _.flatten<string | Item>([arr, item]);
```